# what is the alternative way for posting on friends wall after February 2013 Breaking Changes

Tags: android

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Accroding to Facebook user cannot post using firendsid/feed after ferbruary 2013 breaking changes i want alternative way how can we post on friensds wall using android SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep reading the changes it does mention that if you want to post to a friends wall then you will need to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).  This is, I assume, to limit the amount of spam posted to friends walls.